# Progressbar for filling TextBox using MVVM Light Toolkit in WinRT

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, windows-runtime

I have a form containing few TextBox elements and a progress bar. I want the progress bar to be updated when the TextBox's have some values assigned.

So when a value is set to a TextBox I increment ProgressPercent if the lenght is different from 0;

The problem is that I don't know what condition to use to check if any value was set before and to decrement if the TextBox will become blank again.

Bellow you have my code so far

**ViewModel**

```
private string firstName { get; set; }
private string progressPercent { get; set; }

public string FirstName
{
    get
    {
        return this.firstName;
    }
    set
    {
        this.firstName = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.FirstName);

        var vm1 = (new ViewModelLocator()).MainViewModel;
        if (value.Length != 0)              //   Checks the string length 
        {
            vm1.ProgressPercent += 3;
        }
    }
}
public int ProgressPercent
{
    get
    {
        return this.progressPercent;
    }
    set
    {
        this.progressPercent = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.ProgressPercent);
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<StackPanel>
    <ProgressBar x:Name="progressBar1" 
                 Value="{Binding ProgressPercent ,Mode=TwoWay}"  
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                 IsIndeterminate="False" 
                 Maximum="100"
                 Width="800"/>
    <TextBlock Text="First Name"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="FirstNameTextBox" Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: to decrease couldn't you just do `else vm1.ProgressPercent-=3` if it's length is 0? Or is that not what you're asking?

Comment: @bill yes, but how do you check if before it had a value, so you can decrease ?

Comment: You could use a bool to track, so when ever you add progress value for the firstname, set `firstNamePoints=true` and if length is 0, check if `firstNamePoints=true` and then set it false and subtract 3

Comment: `var vm1 = (new ViewModelLocator()).MainViewModel;` dafuq did you just use a locator to find the current instance to set a property value on it?

Comment: @Will, i'm setting property in a different viewmodel

Comment: Good! That made me top lip sweat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not notify property changes if the property did not change. You always can know for sure when it becomes empty and the other way around.

```
    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.firstName;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.firstName != value)
            {
                bool oldValueIsEmpty = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.firstName);
                this.firstName = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.FirstName);

                var vm1 = (new ViewModelLocator()).MainViewModel;
                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))              //   Checks the string length 
                {
                    vm1.ProgressPercent -= 3;
                }
                else if (oldValueIsEmpty)
                {
                    vm1.ProgressPercent += 3;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Good point, I like your approach better than the OP's current method.

Comment: Only suggestion I would make, is perhaps use `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` (If programming this on .Net 4+) instead of `IsNullOrEmpty` if you don't want just empty spaces registering as a new value

Comment: The problem with this aproach is that if you edit the value after it was set the first time, the ProgressPercent will be increased. How do you check if this is only an edit?

Comment: You're right, added a few checks, the property is too messy though, I would put it in a separate method.

Answer (score 2):

Track with a bool like this:

```
 private bool firstNamePoints=false;
 public string FirstName
 {
    get
    {
        return this.firstName;
    }
    set
    {
        this.firstName = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.FirstName);

        var vm1 = (new ViewModelLocator()).MainViewModel;
        if (value.Length != 0)              //   Checks the string length 
        {
          if(!firstNamePoints)
           {
            vm1.ProgressPercent += 3;
            firstNamePoints=true;
           }
        }
        else
        {
          if(firstNamePoints)
          {
            vm1.ProgressPercent -= 3;
            firstNamePoints=false;
          }
         }
    }
}
```